# How would you go about in ordering a has_many association based on an association two levels deep?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations

I have 4 models

1. Restaurant
2. Location
3. City
4. State

The dichotomy pretty much flows in that order. The I've run into a wall where I wanted to order have restaurant locations ordered by the name of the state they belong to in ascending order. I tried to do the following in my has_many declaration but got a SQL error:

```
ArgumentError (Direction "{:state=>{:name=>:asc}}" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"])
```

This is how my models are setup

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations, -> { order(city: { state: { name: :asc } }) }, dependent: :destroy
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :states
end
```

What do I need to alter to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full set of associations to traverse from any level to another:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cities, through: :locations
  has_many :states, through: :cities
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :city
  has_one :state, through: :city
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :locations
  has_many :restaurants, through: :locations
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities
  has_many :locations, through: :cities
  has_many :restaurants, through: :locations
end
```

`.order` does not accept nested hashes. It only accepts `{ foo: :asc, bar: :desc ...}` as hash arguments along with positional arguments. You can use a string key to specify a column on another table `.order("states.name" => :asc)`.  See the docs for the [signature](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order).

While you can order by a joined table by using a string `.order('states.name ASC')` or string key that must be done together with a join and is not really a good idea to define this in the association itself as it will have very surprising effects if you for example call `Restaurant.joins(:locations)...` and it wildly starts joining other tables left and right and reordering the query.

Instead you want to create a scope that gives you the records in a particular order.

```
class Location 
  # ...
  scope :order_by_state, -> { joins(:state).order('states.name ASC') }
end
```

Comment: If I use the provided scope in this way: `has_many :locations, -> { order_by_state }, dependent: :destroy` I get the error: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Location' to association named 'state'; perhaps you misspelled it?)`. Am I implementing this correctly?

Comment: Don't apply the scope to the association. I thought I was really clear on that one. If you want the locations ordered by state just do `Location.order_by_state`.

Comment: "Can't join 'Location' to association named 'state'; perhaps you misspelled it?" means that you probably did not add the association that its supposed to go though or your misuse of a scope is using it before its actually defined.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand you correctly, I would have to add an association extension to use this scope in the has_many declaration?

Comment: No not really. You need to drop the idea that your going to use it on the association. While you can create special associations with order and stuff applied it's not a good idea to do it by default as order applies to the whole query.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.

Comment: You can create an extension though but you would call that as for example restaurant.locations.order_by_state

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again.